# PHP, Inserting a line into CSV using fputcsv

Tags: php, csv

I have a file that has the following structure :

[image]

I'm trying to insert a new line at the end using this function :

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',true);//At the beginning of the php file
$handle = fopen("File.csv", "r+");
    $line = array(
        [0] => Trussville
        [1] => L01
        [2] => 8765
        [3] => this is , a sample (xx)
    );
    fputcsv($handle, $line, ',', '"'); 
    fclose($handle);
```

The result I get is as following :
[image]

Can help me please ?
Thanks

Comment: You'll need to jump to the end of the file after opening it using fseek()

Comment: Can you explain more please?

Answer (score 1):

before writing, position the file pointer to the end of the file, like so:

```
...
fseek($handle, 0, SEEK_END);
fputcsv($handle, $line, ',', '"');
```

Comment: You could also just open the file in append mode: `$handle = fopen('file.csv', 'a');`